# Is this the most efficient way of doing recursion for checking whether a string is a palindrome?

Tags: java

```
public boolean isPalindrome3(String input, int index, int length)
{
    if(index > (length-1-index))
        return true;

    else if(input.charAt(index)!=input.charAt(length-1-index))
        return false;

    else
        return isPalindrome3(input, index + 1, length);



}
```

Here initially i pass the input string, 0, input.length()

Comment: I would just pass the `start` and `end` *indices*. Passing the `length` (besides *already* being a property of a String) makes for extra math. Then the recursive case is `f(str,start+1,end-1)` which is easier [for me] to visualize as well ..

Comment: recursivity is not necessary for checking whether a string is a palindrome. It's correct and probably there is no other version but it's less efficient than the non-recursive version.

Comment: @Razvan As a general rule, when non-essential recursion is requested, it's homework.

Comment: corsiKa I assure you it is not homework. I usually don't end up implementing recursion in the most simplified way and I read this question somewhere which said you need to use recursion. As you can see I have implemented something that is correct and I'm not clueless. I posted a question on SO because I thought the whole point of using SO is to better your skills through learning if there are simpler ways of doing something or not.

Comment: I don't know where you read that you need to use recursion for this, but that is most definitely wrong. It's easy to do using iteration and any (sane) iterative solution will be more efficient than using recursion.

Comment: You don't really even need iteration either. Just reverse the string and check equality. `yourString.equals(new StringBuffer(yourString).reverse().toString())`. Less efficient than your solution but much simpler to read and debug.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to use recursion, here's a much more efficient check for palindrome:

```
public boolean isPalindrome3(String input)
{
    for (int start = 0, end = input.length() - 1; start < end; ) {
        if (input.charAt(start++) != input.charAt(end--)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str, int offset)
{    
    int rightOffset = str.length() - offset - 1;
    if (offset <= rightOffset)
    {
        char c1 = str.charAt(offset);
        char c2 = str.charAt(rightOffset);
        if (c1 != c2) return false;

        return isPalindrome(str, offset + 1);
    } else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Differences with your code:

- Do not pass the `length`, because that is a String property
- unwrap the character comparation
- nice code formatting
- improved efficiency, by creating a local variable rightOffset.

Comment: Why would you write it like that? It requires a multiply and it looks up the characters before checking whether you're already done. (By the way, OP's code only goes halfway through the string as well.)

Comment: @TedHopp: Fair point, I edited it :) The multiplication is to make sure we only check the half of the string. (Edit to your edit: oh, yes. Indeed I see, now. A bit confusing code)

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes, indeed. You are right again :) But I made it even better, check out the new code :)

Comment: why is it better to calculate string length everytime than passing a length parameter ?

Comment: @Phoenix: Maybe you are a C++ guy? But the String.length() method in Java simply returns an int. It doesn't calculate the length. The length of the string is stored inside the String class as a class member.

Comment: Okay. Then why is it better to create a local variable as opposed to computing the right offset twice?

Comment: Because, you're obviously computing it twice. Plus: computing it requires a push to the stack. So, you save one calculation and one push (and probably a some other things since the code runs in a JVM and not native).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseString(String s) {       
    byte[] array = s.getBytes();
    byte swap;

    for( int i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i < array.length / 2; i++, j--) {
        swap = array[ j ];
        array[ j ] = array[ i ];
        array[ i ] = swap;
    }

    return (new String(array));
}

if(myString.equals(reverseString(myString)))
    // is palindrome
```